# Как реализовать запись в файл с переменной с помощью curl?

Tags: curl, php

В нижеприведенным данном коде скачивается  и записывается файл 11.zip:

```
     $ch = curl_init ();
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://sotmarket.ru/xml_files/11.zip");
     $fp = fopen ("11.zip", "w+");
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://sotmarket.ru/xml_files/11.zip");
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
     curl_exec ($ch);
     curl_close ($ch);
     fclose ($fp);
```

Подскажите, как реализовать запись в файл с переменной. Вот, например,
есть файл `$my_file = '11.zip'`, как его записать на сервер именно с помощью curl? 
`file_put_contents()`, `fwrite()` не подходят для решения задачи.

В вышепоказанном скрипте содержимое курл берет по ссылке, а нужно, чтоб он брал с переменной.

Comment: @Юрий Зав, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Либо так:

```
$name = "11.zip";
if(is_writable($name)) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $fp = fopen ($name, "w+");
    $ch = curl_init("http://sotmarket.ru/xml_files/{$name}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}else{
    echo 'Файл недоступен для записи';
}
```

Либо так:

```
$name = "11.zip";
if(is_writable($name)) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $ch = curl_init("http://sotmarket.ru/xml_files/{$name}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $file = fopen($name, "w+");
    fputs($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
}else{
    echo 'Файл недоступен для записи';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, второй вариант подошел.

Answer (score 0):

Че-то не ясно. Смысл curl-а брать данные по ссылке, 
Цитата из вики:
"cURL — свободная (распространяемая по лицензии MIT), кроссплатформенная служебная программа командной строки, позволяющая взаимодействовать с множеством различных серверов по множеству различных протоколов с синтаксисом URL." 
Т.е. если не нужно брать данные из URL, то и curl брать незачем.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
```

нужно определять перед:

```
curl_exec ($ch);
```

То есть, заменить:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
$curl_exec ($ch);
```

на:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
$curl_exec ($ch);
```